# Android: checkbox listener

Tags: java, android, android-checkbox

I want to put a Listener over a `CheckBox`. I looked for info and it is like this:

```
satView = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sateliteCheckBox);

satView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        if (isChecked){
            // perform logic
        }
    }

});
```

The problem is that Eclipse thinks it's an `OnCheckedChangeListener` for a `RadioGroup` and it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 316, accepted):

You can do this:

```
satView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

       }
   }
);
```

Comment: Thank you and here is how to remove it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881817/removing-strikethrough-from-textview

Comment: `OnCheckedChangeListener` and `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener` are different.

Comment: for kotlin
satView.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, _ ->
            if (buttonView.isChecked) {
                // perform action
            } else {
                // perform action
            }
        }

Answer (score 61):

you may also go for a simple `View.OnClickListener`:

```
satView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(((CompoundButton) view).isChecked()){
            System.out.println("Checked");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Un-Checked");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It's really only one working solution when I wanted to listen a checkbox **click action**, not its **state** like others solutions recommend there.

Comment: the best way to set check listener for checkbox in recycleView

Answer (score 22):

You get the error because you imported wrong package.You should `import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;`

So the callback should be :

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
        // Perform logic
    }
});
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```java
satView = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.sateliteCheckBox);

satView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
          if (buttonView.isChecked()) { 
                // checked
          } 
          else 
          {
                // not checked
          }
    }

});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

Translation of the accepted answer by Chris into Kotlin:

```
val checkBox: CheckBox = findViewById(R.id.chk)
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
    // Code here 
}
```

Comment: Note: If the buttonView is not used: "{ _, isChecked ->"

Answer (score 4):

Change `RadioGroup group` with `CompoundButton buttonView` and then press Ctrl+Shift+O to fix your imports.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
satView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if (isChecked){
                // perform logic
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use this code.

```
public class MySampleActivity extends Activity {
    CheckBox cb1, cb2, cb3, cb4;
    LinearLayout l1, l2, l3, l4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
        cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb2);
        cb3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb3);
        cb4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb4);
        l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l1);
        l2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l2);
        l3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l3);
        l4 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l4);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MyCheckedChangeListener(1));
        cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MyCheckedChangeListener(2));
        cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MyCheckedChangeListener(3));
        cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MyCheckedChangeListener(4));
    }

    public class MyCheckedChangeListener implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
        int position;

        public MyCheckedChangeListener(int position) {
            this.position = position;
        }

        private void changeVisibility(LinearLayout layout, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                l1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            switch (position) {
                case 1:
                    changeVisibility(l1, isChecked);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    changeVisibility(l2, isChecked);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    changeVisibility(l3, isChecked);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    changeVisibility(l4, isChecked);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing a 'LinearLayout' to your 'changeVisibility(LinearLayout layout, boolean isChecked)' method yet you're only changing one layout's visibility each time?

Answer (score 2):

```
h.chk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        CheckBox chk=(CheckBox)view; // important line and code work
        if(chk.isChecked())
        {
            Message.message(a,"Clicked at"+position);
        }
        else
        {
            Message.message(a,"UnClick");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can make this answer better by [editing it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39051766/edit) to explain how does it work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to do this in Kotlin with the interface implementation.

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity(),CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

      val yourCheckBox = findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.check_box)
      yourCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this)

    }

 override fun onCheckedChanged(buttonView: CompoundButton?, isChecked: Boolean) {
        when(buttonView?.id){
            R.id.check_box -> Log.d("Checked: ","$isChecked")
        }
    }

}
```