# How to sum checkboxes value in android?

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a problem in java.

```
package apa.y;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class myprice extends Activity  {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    CheckBox book,pencil;
    TextView total;
    int sum=0;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mymain);
    pencil = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pencil);
    book = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.book);
    total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        sum = 0;
        if (pencil.isChecked()) {sum += 10;}else{sum +=0;}
        if (book.isChecked())   {sum += 5;}else{sum +=0;}

        total.setText("Total: "+sum);

    }
}
```

If book and pencil are checkbox and 1 textview, how to sum it? My existing code didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you clicking on? The checkboxes? Then you need some kind of listener for those views. Two options are provided here: [Android: checkbox listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386832/android-checkbox-listener)

If you want to use the onClick method as you have it now, change this:

```
public class myprice extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {
```

And make sure that you set the OnClickListener for both checkboxes:

```
pencil = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.pencil);
pencil.setOnClickListener(this);
book = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.book);
book.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: wait me please I'll try. .

Comment: helooooooo IT WORK! THANK YOU :). amazing hihihi

Answer (score 0):

Create an `OnCheckedChangeListener` and set it to all your `CheckBox`. then on check box checked +1 in an Integer variable and on unchecked -1 from Integer variable. Now you have the latest total sum value of check boxes in your Integer variable.

You can do something like this :

```
int mCheckSum = 0;

private OnCheckedChangeListener dmCheckChangeListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        if (isChecked) {
            mCheckSum += 1;
        } else if (isChecked == false) {
            if (mCheckSum > 0) {
                mCheckSum -= 1;
            }
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: wait me pleaseeeee. I'll try

Comment: Welcome. If it worked then you can mark my answer as correct.

Comment: oh I see. nice to know you :)

Comment: Hehehe You can only mark one question as correct. You have marked other answer as correct..but its okay.. :)