# Toggle state from broadcast recive android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, oncreate, onresume, togglebutton

I have a toggle that when BATTERY_LOW is true turns off the wifi:

```
public void getToggle(View view) { 
    // Is the toggle on?
   boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked(); 
    if (on) {
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    ComponentName compName = 
    new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), 
        LowBatteryReceiver.class);
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        compName,
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, 
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    } else {                
           PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
           ComponentName compName = 
           new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), 
           LowBatteryReceiver.class);
           pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
           compName,
           PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 
           PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);           
      }
    }
```

here the wifi code:

```
public class LowBatteryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
                        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
    }
}


public class OkBatteryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
                        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

How can i "remember" the choice of the toggle when i go out from my application and open it again? I know that i have to write something at `onResume` and in the `onCreate` but i don't know what when i use the BroadcastReceiver.I think i have to check if the `COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED` or `COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED` right?.Someone can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read about saving data in Android:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

```
//set Preference
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();

//get Preference
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
```

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand..where have i to put this code exactly?

Comment: I have no idea how can do it. What have i put onResume?

Comment: use the get Preference instead of ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked() and set a OnClickListener to the togglebutton in which you set the Preference.
How to add a Listener see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386832/android-checkbox-listener