# Removing Strikethrough from TextView

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, flags, strikethrough

I'm using this line below in order to set a strikethrough on my TextView:

```
tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

However later on in the Fragment, if they click the TextView again, I would like the strikethrough to be removed. What line of code can I use to simply make the TextView display the text in the normal format again?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I ended up finding this online:

```
tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
```

This successfully removes the strikethrough and therefore I called this in my `OnListItemClick` method after carrying out a check in the database I made to see if the item had already been striked through (purchased in my case).

Answer (score 22):

Another way is to simply set value of `setPaintFlags` to Zero.

```
tv.setPaintFlags(0)
```

**NOTE:**

This will remove strike through your text and other Typeface design, You are free to use in case it doesn't applied to your view.

Comment: this will also remove the other paint features like the Typeface design off the text and make it look like a skeleton without flesh on it!

Answer (score 3):

You can set an `OnClickListener` on the `TextView`, reset the paint flags, and call its `invalidate()` so it redraws itself.

Comment: I like your idea and I'm sure I could get that method to work, however I found a simpler answer online. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Setting up AntiAlias helped me to make text look less distored

**Kotlin**

```
tv.paintFlags = Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG
```