# Android widget - How to remove text strike through from remote view

Tags: android, android-widget, android-remoteview

How to remove text strike through from remote view.

Here is my code, but it is not working --

To add strike through text(working) -

```
views.setInt(R.id.widgetTitle, "setPaintFlags", Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
```

To remove strike through text (not working)-

```
views.setInt(R.id.widgetTitle, "setPaintFlags", Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG & (~Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG));
```

Full  code -

```
            if (item.isCheck()) {
                views.setTextColor(R.id.widgetTitle, Color.WHITE);
                views.setInt(R.id.widgetTitle, "setPaintFlags", Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            } else {
                views.setTextColor(R.id.widgetTitle, Color.WHITE);
                views.setInt(R.id.widgetTitle, "setPaintFlags", Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG & (~Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG));
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to "unstrikethrough" the `TextView`, it is sufficient to simply set the `Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG` if you want normal text (that's because `setPaintFlags()` does not add the new and the previous flags, it just sets the new flags):

```
if (item.isCheck()) {
            views.setTextColor(R.id.widgetTitle, Color.WHITE);
            views.setInt(R.id.widgetTitle, "setPaintFlags",
                         Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        } else {
            views.setTextColor(R.id.widgetTitle, Color.WHITE);
            views.setInt(R.id.widgetTitle, "setPaintFlags", Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        }
```

If you want to preserve more than one flag which was previously set while removing the strikethrough effect, I'd like to point you to this [post by edwoolard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18882030/5015207)