# How to create Alertbox from dynamic Checkbox in Android?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-alertdialog

I have created six dynamic **Checkbox** for my app and i want to **Pop-up** an **AlertBox** if the check box is checked but i am finding any result from my code. I am true value to the checkbox but no **AlertBox** is coming.

**Java Code :**

```
package com.example.mycheckbox;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ii);
        CheckBox[] cb = new CheckBox[6];

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
        {
            cb[i] = new CheckBox(this);
            cb[i].setText("Dynamic Checkbox " + i);
            cb[i].setId(i + 6);

            if (cb[i].isChecked())
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder myalert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                myalert.setTitle("Demo Title - "+i).setMessage(" Message from - "+i).setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();
            }

            ll.addView(cb[i]);                       
        }
    }
}
```

I want to pop an `AlertDialog` for each `CheckBox` if that is checked.

Answer (score 2):

The `AlertDialog` isn't showing cause you didn't create the `AlertDialog` object from the `AlertDialog.Builder`. Create ab `AlertDialog` object as below and then call `show()` method using that object to show the `Dialog`.

Another thing, you didn't assign the `Listener` to those `CheckBox`. Now set the listener to them and show the dialog as below...

```
cb[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        AlertDialog.Builder myalert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        myalert.setTitle("Demo Title - "+i);
        myalert.setMessage(" Message from - "+i);
        myalert.setNeutralButton("Close", null);

        AlertDialog dialog = myalert.create();
        dialog.show();
   }
}
```

Comment: No friend , not showing any alert box.... i think your code is quite perfect but not getting any result....

Comment: Yes man, getting the alertbox but it's showing the last index value for each alert box , so the result i am getting for each alertbox is Demo Title - 6 , Message from - 6 ....

Comment: Please, try it yourself...I have to go cause its late night here...if you didn't get any solution then I will check it in the morning...best of luck...and if its helpful then don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you.[Checkbox Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386832/android-checkbox-listener). Add them while creating the checkbox. Or refer to the checkbox created by the id you are setting and set a listener then.

Answer (score 0):

As default, they won't be checked, so no popup will be shown, you should add a listener if someone check it or not.

```
cb[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
          // alert dialog 

      }
});
```

or you can implements OnCheckedChangeListener and use one listener for all checkboxes.

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    //

}
```

Comment: No Man getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ... length=6 , index=6 error .... i don't know how it is coming ??