# How I know CheckBox is clicked or not clicked?

Tags: android

How I know CheckBox is clicked or not clicked?
Thank all

xml file:

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox" />
```

java file:

```
public class Setting extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);

}
}
```

Comment: `((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox).setOnCheckedChangedListener(...)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: checkbox listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386832/android-checkbox-listener)

Answer (score 0):

```
//declaring the checked variable at the top
checked=false;
if(checkbox.isChecked())
 {
 checked=true;
 }
 else
 {
 checked=false;
 }
```

Comment: boolean checked = checkbox.isChecked();

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
if (cb.isChecked()) {
    // code to run when checked
} else {
    // code to run when unchecked
}
```

Comment: this is true answer.How to set clicked in java code?

Answer (score 0):

```
try this hope it will help you:   
checkbox    mchk1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chk11);
Boolean cBox1;

SharedPreferences pref =   getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); 

        cBox1=pref.getBoolean("check1", false);

 if(cBox1==true){
            mchk1.setChecked(true);
            //Rb1.setChecked(true);
        }

SharedPreferences pref =   getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); 

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

                if(mchk1.isChecked() ){

                    editor.putBoolean("check1", true);
                }
 else if(!mchk1.isChecked()  )
{
                    editor.putBoolean("check1", false);
                }
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in your activity as below,

```
public class Setting extends ActionBarActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

CheckBox myCheckBox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);

    myCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    myCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if(isChecked){
        //here the checkBox is checked
    }else {
        //here the checkBox is not checked
    }        
}
}
```

Let me know if it works...