# How to pass the values while check box is unchecked

Tags: android, checkbox

I have 3 check boxes..I have added click listener for each check  boxes..based on the check box click i had set the values inside click listener...After adding the check box click,there will be possibility to uncheck it while updating the check box...

While clicking the check box i am setting isSelected =1...Like the way i need to set isSelected =0 while it is unchecked...How is it possible..Please help me to find out

This is my check box click listener1

```
checkBox_onEventDay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    response = 1;
                    try {
                        //Here we are getting the date from btn_Date(date picker)
                        //date and time format changed here
                        String eventDate = btn_Date.getText().toString();
                        DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy");
                        Date date1 = date.parse(eventDate);
                        DateFormat convertDate = new SimpleDateFormat(" dd.MM.yyyy");
                        eventDate = convertDate.format(date1);
                        eventMO.setEventDate(eventDate);
                        //here we are setting event date as reminder date..
                        //Because it is on event day checkbox
                        reminderDate = eventDate;
                        eventReminderDaysDetails(response, reminderDate);
                        Toast.makeText(OccasionActivity.this,
                                "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    } catch (ParseException pExp) {
                        pExp.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Am I missing something in your description? Why not just use if (v.isChecked()) isSelected = 1; else isSelected = 0; ?

Comment: Or better yet, isSelected = v.isChecked ? 1 : 0;

Comment: @ Cody Harness.. I cant get you..can you please explain me clearly

Comment: If you want your variable to be 1 when the box is selected and 0 when it is not, then all you need to do is put that code at the top of your onClick method.

Comment: ok .Thank you..I will try this and tel u

Comment: why are you not using a [`CheckChangedListener`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8386876/1529129)

Comment: @Rahul How it is different from click listener

Comment: CheckChangedListener gives you event when check in your checkbox changes from true to false or false to true. it also gives you current state of checkbox in same event

Comment: Ok rahul.I will try that

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you have an unchecked check box in the beginning. If not, you can initialize the value of `isSelected` accordingly. You need to handle `onClick` like this:

```
final boolean isSelected = false;
        checkBox_onEventDay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(isSelected) {
                    isSelected = false;
                    // now check box is unchecked
                } else {
                    isSelected = true;
                    // now the checkbox is checked
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is my question is ..While clicking the check box,i will set 4 attributes like type id,is selected,date...I will add these details to data base(is selected=1)...At the time of update if i uncheck the already clicked check box means i need to set the isselected=0;

Comment: ok, so then also you need to record at which positions your check boxes are being toggled and then for those positions, do the required work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code :

```
  if(cb.isChecked()) {
    isSelected  = 1 ;
    Log.e("Checkbox is checked" , ""+isSelected);
  } else {
    isSelected  = 0 ;
    Log.e("Checkbox is unchecked" , ""+isSelected);
  }
```

As simple as that.

Comment: its not working...while check the check box else method is not called

Comment: If you check the check box your value is set as 1 and if you uncheck the check box your value is set as 0.

Comment: @sathya. nagaraj19 I have added braces to KishuDroid's code. Try now

Comment: while uncheck the check box it shows null pointer exception...i dont know  why]