# Controlling state of checkbox based on state of other checkboxes in android

Tags: java, android

I have three checkboxes and if any two of them are selected I want to disable the third checkbox immediately. I am not getting how to proceed.

Comment: I have references to three checkboxes but I am not getting any logic to proceed forward. I atleast need logic to move forward

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386832/android-checkbox-listener

Comment: I think it's strange that this question got at least two upvotes. Downvote from here. As stated above, you should show what you have done so far and narrow down the problem instead of asking for a full-blown solution. Also describe what resources you have read (developer docs, tutorials etc.) in order to get an understanding of the problem at hand. We are here to help, but we are not going to do all your work for you. Show some commitment, please.

Comment: @ janus as I have stated earlier I just wanted the logic to proceed forward. And if you really want to know what I have read and what code I have written, don't worry as soon as I get the required result using the logic provided by my fellow mates I will post it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manage your CheckBoxes in a List, so you can iterate over them.

```
List<CheckBox> boxes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Assign them like so (in `onCreate()` of your activity)

```
 boxes.add((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox1));
 boxes.add((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox2));
 boxes.add((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox3));
```

Add an `onCheckedChangeListener` like this:

```
for(CheckBox box : boxes){
        box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                manageBoxes();
            }
        });
    }
```

and finally your `manageBoxes()`

```
private void manageBoxes(){
    int count = 0;
    for(CheckBox box : boxes){
        count += box.isChecked()?1:0;
    }

    if(count>=2){
        for(CheckBox box : boxes){
            box.setEnabled(box.isChecked());
            box.setClickable(box.isChecked()); // not sure if needed
        }
    }else{
        // reset all boxes
        for(CheckBox box : boxes){
            box.setEnabled(true);
            box.setClickable(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Just a quick and dirty thought. Hope this works.
Plus: This is scalable, so you could include some more checkboxes if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Add a change handler or a click handler on each of the checkboxes and let it call a small method that is responsible for checking the value of each checkbox: if two of them are true disable the third one.

For example:

```
checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            handleCheckBoxes();
        }
    });
//Do this for all the checkboxes

    private void handleCheckBoxes(){
        int checkedCount = 0;
        CheckBox uncheckedBox = null;

        if(checkBox1.isChecked()){ 
            checkedCount++; 
        }
        else{
            uncheckedBox = checkBox1;
        }

        if(checkBox2.isChecked()){
            checkedCount++; 
        }
        else{
            uncheckedBox = checkBox2;
        }

        if(checkBox3.isChecked()){
            checkedCount++; 
        }
        else{
            uncheckedBox = checkBox3;
        }

        if(checkedCount == 2){
            uncheckedBox .setEnabled(false);
        }
        else{
            //enable all checkboxes
            checkBox1.setEnables(true);
            checkBox2.setEnables(true);
            checkBox3.setEnables(true);
        }
```

Comment: do you have any demo or example for it ?

Comment: yes for example I want to calculate voltage then I need any of the two quantities from current resistance or power. So if user selects current and resistance checkboxes then the power checkbox should get disabled

Comment: @NikeshPatel Please check the code in the edited post. I did not test it but you can see the logic... hope this helps

Comment: This looks pretty ugly imo.

Comment: @miva2 this is not a code to deploy man. He asked for logic this is just to show the procedure.

Comment: @miva2 oh i just checked your answer, you're right! It's much cleaner that way...

Comment: @Youssef I am working on the the code provided by you. Will get to you soon

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement this way :

```
 private ArrayList<Integer> integers = null;
     integers = new ArrayList<>();
      chkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try {
                            int position = (int) yourview.getTag();

                            if (chkBox.isChecked()) {
                                    integers.add(position);
                                    chkBox.setChecked(true);

                            } else {
                                if (integers.size() > 0) {
                             for (int i=0; i<integers.size(); i++)                                 {
                                        if (integers.get(i) == position) {
                                            integers.remove(i);
                                }
                            }
                });
    if (integers.size() > 2) {
                   //Disable your third checkbox
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code this would be:

Create variable to hold the number of checkboxes checked, let's call it `amountChecked`
When a checkbox gets checked => increment the `amountChecked`
When a checkbox gets checked => check if the `amountChecked` is equal or greater than the `allowedAmountChecked` (in your case this is 2)
=> if it is greater or equal to the `allowedAmountChecked` then disable the remaining checkboxes

Comment: But with a counter like that, you still have to take care of display rotations. storing the counter in savedInstanceState eg.