# How do I uncheck checkbox upon new spinner value?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

Let's say for vocSpinner value = "Combat/Service" and popSpinner value = "NSmen" and I check cb1. It will give a list. However, when I change popSpinner to "Regular/NSF" it will change to another list (which is correct) but how do I uncheck the checkbox as well without creating another data that overlay. The codes I provided doesn't seem to work and I can't work it out. All help are welcome, thanks in advance!

imgur.com/a/1wt4N [Screenshot of app]

```
private String[] vocSpinner;
private String[] popSpinner;

private List<Standard> standardList = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private StandardsAdapter sAdapter;
private CheckBox cb1;
private CheckBox cb2;

cb1 = (CheckBox) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pushUp);
cb2 = (CheckBox) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.sitUp);

this.vocSpinner = new String[]{
            "CDO/Diver/Gds/Fitness Spec", "Combat/Service"
    };

this.popSpinner = new String[]{
            "NSmen", "Regular/NSF", "Pre-enlistee"
    };

final Spinner v = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner_Voc);
final Spinner p = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner_PopGp);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapterV = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, vocSpinner);
    v.setAdapter(adapterV);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapterP = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, popSpinner);
    p.setAdapter(adapterP);

v.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            standardList.clear();
            cb1.setEnabled(true);
            cb2.setEnabled(true);
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    if (p.getSelectedItem().equals("NSmen")) {
                        cb1.setChecked(false);
                        cb2.setChecked(false);
                        addStandardToList("Gold - $500", ">89pts");
                        addStandardToList("Silver - $300", ">74pts");
                        addStandardToList("Incentive - $200", ">60pts");
                        addStandardToList("Pass", ">50pts");
                        sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();} 
                    else if (p.getSelectedItem().equals("Regular/NSF")) {
                        cb1.setChecked(false);
                        cb2.setChecked(false);
                        addStandardToList("Gold - $300", ">89pts");
                        addStandardToList("Silver - $200", ">74pts");
                        addStandardToList("Incentive", "NA");
                        addStandardToList("Pass", ">60pts");
                        sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: So what you need is on selecting any other spinner values your textbox should by default be unchecked? And if yes, what values should your list show assuming your list is being filtered by checkbox. Should the list have values with checkbox checked or unchecked?

Comment: Yes. The list should show values with the checkbox unchecked. Is it also possible to do when I uncheck the checkbox, it goes back to the unchecked checkbox value instead of showing the checked checkbox values

Comment: So in your onItemSelected listener of your spinner you have done cb1.setEnabled(true);
            cb2.setEnabled(true);
Below that you should also do
cb1.setChecked(false);
            cb2.setChecked(false);

Comment: Do it for both the spinners onItemSelect Method

Comment: Oh great, it is solved!

Comment: So the first part should work with this where your selectedchecbox will become unselected.

Comment: I guess you saved the day again my friend, haha :)

Comment: for the second part where on unchecking as well you want to refresh the list you have to do that in your onCheckedChanged part where you have handled the checkbox checking and do same things for isChecked=false as well as isChecked=true;

Comment: For the second part, I apologize but I don't really understand it. Here's the current code for the checkbox part https://pastebin.com/S3Hb1mSa

Comment: Looks like you are doing the same thing on checked change of both the checkboxes. Ideally put that code in common method and call that method. But from the looks of it, the data should change if you deselect your checkbox as well. What is the issue you are seeing.

Comment: The data does not change if I deselect my checkbox (It does not refresh the listview).

Comment: Can you add some logs in your if condition inside oncheckedchange to see where its going on deselecting. For me if lets say both are selected initially and if you deselect 1 the data will change

Comment: Also, when I check both checkboxes at once, it doesn't show only 1 list but both list at once as shown here (http://imgur.com/a/EJF6q)

Comment: Ok if only 1 of them is selected and you again deselct it, the data will not change because your if condition remains the same in that scenario. cb1.isChecked() && cb2.isChecked() will always come false if only 1 is checked and your dat for else is same in all cases

Comment: By default all checkbox are uncheck. So if I check one, the list will change (working as intended) but if I undo the check, the list still remains (checked checkbox list) instead of changing to unchecked checkbox list.

Comment: True that, how do I change the code to make it function properly then?

Comment: yes this happens because if only 1 checkbox is checked cb1.isChecked() && cb2.isChecked() will always be false. so it will always go in else of your if so no change there. You need to modify the logic of your if else statement based on your requirement

Comment: So you have to think through. if 1 is selected what should be the list else if 2 are selected what should be the value of list and populate list accordingly. IT will depend on your requirement of how to show data

Comment: I have played around my codes but it doesn't not work. I tried adding {} after my if else condition and it does not overlay the 2 lists anymore but it does not show the appropriate list when 2 is checked.

Comment: Ok so you are anyways clearing the list at the start of selection so each checkbox when checked will clear the list first. then its all the matter of what values we add to the list afterwords in your if statement. Lets say you have 4 values 1,2,3,4. Now if cb1 selected add 1,2. if cb1 and cb2 both are selected add 1,2,3 else if only cb2 is selected add 1,2,4 and so on. So this combination of 1,2,3,4 adding you need to define based on your app logic and requirement. Not sure how i can help in logic though

Comment: The only thing I wanna do is if either cb1 or cb2 is checked, display list where Pass >38pts, if both checked display list where Pass >25pts.

Comment: if (cb1.isChecked() || cb2.isChecked()) {
                    // list code
                    } 
                    else if (cb1.isChecked() && cb2.isChecked()) {
                    // list code  
                    }

Comment: What happens if both are not checked?

Comment: It will display the list based on the spinner listener.

Comment: That it will not do automatically as its not related to spinner. You have to manually force the spinner selection. Check This. https://pastebin.com/ipWzCmtg

Comment: I have done for 1 checkedChange method. You can do the same in another by copy paste. This should work and once you verify mark the answer as complete

Comment: May I know what does your code do?

Comment: What it does is if no checkbox is checked, it is manually selecting the same values of your spinner that were previously selected so that your selection listener of spinner is called and your array is repopulated based on spinner values.

Comment: Alright understood, that's good. However I am still unable to get the logic to display (Pass - >25pts) when both cb is checked.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. copy paste error. so change your else if to else if (cb1.isChecked() || cb2.isChecked()) .
So your first condition should be if (cb1.isChecked() && cb2.isChecked())  then second should be if (cb1.isChecked() || cb2.isChecked())  and third just else. And do it for all

Comment: added as an answer for you to check and accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your onItemSelected listener of your spinner you have done

```
cb1.setEnabled(true); 
cb2.setEnabled(true);
```

Below that you should also do

```
cb1.setChecked(false); 
cb2.setChecked(false);
```

also if no checkbox is checked, it is manually selecting the same values of your spinner that were previously selected so that your selection listener of spinner is called and your array is repopulated based on spinner values. For that do the following in your else -

```
String getSelectedItemP = p.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    p.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter<String>)p.getAdapter()).getPosition(getSelectedItemP));
                    String getSelectedItemV = v.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    v.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter<String>)p.getAdapter()).getPosition(getSelectedItemV));
```

So your one if condition onCheckedChanged would look like

```
 if (v.getSelectedItem().equals("CDO/Diver/Gds/Fitness Spec") || v.getSelectedItem().equals("Combat/Service") && p.getSelectedItem().equals("NSmen")) {
                if (cb1.isChecked() && cb2.isChecked()) {
                    addStandardToList("Gold - $500", "NA");
                    addStandardToList("Silver - $300", "NA");
                    addStandardToList("Incentive - $200", "NA");
                    addStandardToList("Pass", ">25pts");
                    sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else if (cb1.isChecked() || cb2.isChecked()) {
                    addStandardToList("Gold - $500", "NA");
                addStandardToList("Silver - $300", "NA");
                addStandardToList("Incentive - $200", "NA");
                addStandardToList("Pass", ">38pts");
                sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else{
                    // select spinner again here manually.
                    String getSelectedItemP = p.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    p.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter<String>)p.getAdapter()).getPosition(getSelectedItemP));
                    String getSelectedItemV = v.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    v.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter<String>)p.getAdapter()).getPosition(getSelectedItemV));
                }
            }
```

Comment: I have implemented the exact code but it still does not work as intended.

Comment: So is it not changing the values when nothing is selected or is it showing wrong values?

Comment: So before, on just the cb1 listener, I have to check cb2 first before checking cb1 to get the (Pass >25pts) list. So I tried implementing the same logic to cb2 listener and now, it's working as intended. Just that the overall code will be a tad messy.

Comment: Alright got everything up and working as intended! My sincerest gratitude again kapsym :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I discovered 2 bugs and have been playing around my codes for half an hour but yet to discover any issue. So basically, upon starting app, I check either cb1 or cb2 and change vocSpinner to the next value and it will display both list as shown in the URL. http://imgur.com/a/T0TBI

Comment: Another is when I check either cb1 or cb2 and change popSpinner to either NSmen or NSF/Regular and it will crash the whole app. Pre-enlistee is fine though.

Comment: The first part is basically your logic again :). The second part i need crash logs.

Comment: I apologize for troubling you but I've spent another 40 mins looking and playing around with the codes but still yield no results. May I ask if you could take a look at my codes? https://pastebin.com/PHFd9be2

Comment: So not sure from this code where is the issue. The basic problem is your list is not getting cleared somewhere? Can you add logs in your code and see.

Comment: I guess I utilized your wrong wrongly String getSelectedItemP = p.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    p.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter<String>)p.getAdapter()).getPosition(getSelectedItemP));
                    String getSelectedItemV = v.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    v.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter<String>)p.getAdapter()).getPosition(getSelectedItemV)); You can see what I do in the else {} becos that's the table that is duplicated.

Comment: } else {
                        String getSelectedItemP = p.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        p.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter<String>) p.getAdapter()).getPosition(getSelectedItemP));
                        String getSelectedItemV = v.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        v.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter<String>) v.getAdapter()).getPosition(getSelectedItemV));
                    } I don't get what this code is doing.

Comment: This code is getting the previous selected value of Padapter from opo spinner and selecting it manually again so that your onselect method of spinner is called. And then it is doing the same thing for v adapter.  so that your list is displayed as per spinner selection. this was as per your requirement that you asked me. It will go in this else if no checkbox is selected

Comment: Yes, but it is not working as intended (I delete the list I manually inserted and just left your code in the else section but it doesn't do anything). But rather when I add the list abv your code, it works.

Comment: this will work only after you have once selected the checkbox and then again deselect it to call the code. You can add log in every if else in your code to understand what part is called when and can change the logic accordingly. i gave the logic to the best understanding of your requirement

Comment: Yup, that's what I did. Check once (Show Pass >38pts) and when I uncheck, the list did not change. Anyway, I fixed the issue where 2 list display both at once (The one I provided w an URL)

Comment: The crash bug too! Basically fixed both at once haha.

Comment: Great. So everything worked out for you. Do upvote the answer as well for your questions when you accept the answer so that the person who helped you is also rewarded on the site :)

Comment: Yup, it's completed. I can't upvote as my rep is insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Get the cb from the following code:

```
View myView = list.getChildAt(index);
CheckBox checkItem = (CheckBox) myView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxId);
checkItem.setChecked(false);
```