# listview checkbox events

Tags: java, android

I have listview with single choice checkboxes like this:

```
checkbox1:
checkbox2:
checkbox3:
```

and three variables

```
int a = 0:
int b = 0:
int c = 0:
```

I want to make variable `a` +1 if `checkbox1` isChecked and when I change my checked for example `checkbox2` I want to make `a` -1 and `b` +1
How can I do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: checkbox listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386832/android-checkbox-listener)

Answer (score 1):

```
checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    a++;
                    b =0;
                    c=0;
                }
            });
checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    b++;
                    a =0;
                    c=0;
                }
            });
checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
               public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                c++;
                a =0;
                b=0;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    a = -1;
                    b = 1;
                }
            });
```