# how to save all check boxes values in arraylist or shareprefrence

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, checkbox

I have made four check boxes. when I check them true it should save in `ArrayList`. Can I save them to the `array list`? and also when I deselect them they should be `removed` from the `list` or `ArrayList`.i have implemented the `checkboxes` and also one select all button to select all `checkboxes` and one `deselect` button on deselect all the values of `checkboxes` should be removed from it.

---

> **My code is**

```
public class SearchFragment extends BaseFragment {
private static final String TAG = null;
String[] name={ "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Japan", "Europe"};
Object arr;
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
TextView tv2
CheckBox abc,abc1,a,b,c;
public static SearchFragment newInstance () {
    return new SearchFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
    tv2=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv2);


    abc=(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.abc);
    a=(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.a);
    b=(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.b);
    c=(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.c);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated (View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);


    tv2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String value=tv2.getText().toString().trim();
            if (value.equals("Select all")){
                abc.setChecked(true);
                a.setChecked(true);
                b.setChecked(true);
                c.setChecked(true);
                tv2.setText("UnSelect all");
                arrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(name));
                Log.e("SELECTED","SELECTED "+arrayList.size());
            }
            else {
                abc.setChecked(false);
                b.setChecked(false);
                a.setChecked(false);
                c.setChecked(false);

                tv2.setText("Select all");
                if (arrayList.size() != 0) {
                    arrayList.clear();

                }
                Log.e("NOT_SELECTED","NOT_SELECTED");
            }
       }
    });
    abc.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                arrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList("Chicago"));
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you post your full code of activity

Comment: I'm not able to put my code here .

Comment: public class SearchFragment extends BaseFragment {
    String[] name={ "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Japan", "Europe"};

    TextView tv2;
    CheckBox abc,a,b,c;
    public static SearchFragment newInstance () {
        return new SearchFragment();
    }

Comment: @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
        tv2=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        abc=(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.abc);
        a=(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.a);
        b=(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.b);
        c=(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.c);
        return view;
    }

Comment: Edit your question and put all of your code @Shabnam

Comment: edited this is my full code u can see it

Comment: I answered your question , Please check it

Comment: plz check i have updated my code i have to do like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use below code to add all of your `checkBox` data to `ArrayList` :

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();  

tv2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String value=tv2.getText().toString().trim();
        if (value.equals("Select all")){
            abc.setChecked(true);
            a.setChecked(true);
            b.setChecked(true);
            c.setChecked(true);
            tv2.setText("Select all");


           //Adding data to ArrayList
           List arrList = Arrays.asList(name);
           arrayList.addAll(arrList);
           arrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));

           //or, Add data into ArrayList Manually
           arrayList.add("Chicago");
           arrayList.add("Los Angeles");
           arrayList.add("Japan");
           arrayList.add("Europe");

        }
        else {
            abc.setChecked(false);
            b.setChecked(false);
            a.setChecked(false);
            c.setChecked(false);

            tv2.setText("Select all");

            //Clear Data from ArrayList
            if(arrayList.size()!=0){
                 arrayList.clear
             }
        }

   }
});
```

> Use Below code to Select & Remove :

```
tv2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String value=tv2.getText().toString().trim();
        if (value.equals("Select all")){
            abc.setChecked(true);
            a.setChecked(true);
            b.setChecked(true);
            c.setChecked(true);
            tv2.setText("Remove all");
            arrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(name));
            Log.e("SELECTED","SELECTED "+arrayList.size());
        }
        else {
            abc.setChecked(false);
            b.setChecked(false);
            a.setChecked(false);
            c.setChecked(false);

            tv2.setText("Select all");
            if (arrayList.size() != 0) {
                arrayList.clear();
            }
           Log.e("NOT_SELECTED","NOT_SELECTED");
        }
   }
});
```

> Add Single Item As below :

**Reference :**

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-element-arraylist-java/
- https://www.javatpoint.com/android-checkbox-example

Code here :

```
abc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
            //is chkIos checked?
    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    arrayList.add("Chicago");
    }
    else 
      // removes Chicago by arrayList Position
      //to avoid runtime exception
                    if(arrayList.contain("Chicago")){
                    arrayList.remove(0);
                    }else{
                   // do your stuff
                      }

  }
});
```

Comment: I'm getting crash on null pointer exception on  arrayList.clear. java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.util.ArrayList.clear()' on a null object reference
                                                                at com.sodick.view.fragments.SearchFragment$1.onClick(SearchFragment.java:96)

Comment: When you have no data on ArrayList and you want to clear arrayList , then it will show you NullPointException. I made edit my answer now check.

Comment: It Seems Correct put Log and check data , Is ArrayList getting the data of your array.@Shabnam

Comment: i'm not getting data in log. can plaese help me in fixing this.

Comment: Sorry , i forget to create ArryList Object , i edited my answer please check it and reply.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
                                                                at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:38)
                                                                at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155)
                                                                at com.sodick.view.fragments.SearchFragment$1.onClick(SearchFragment.java:87)

Comment: //or, Add data into ArrayList Manually use this lines of code and comment above code of adding data into ArrayList

Comment: Add full code : 

//Adding data to ArrayList
           List arrList = Arrays.asList(name);
           arrayList.addAll(arrList);
           arrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));

Comment: now i'm getting all check boxes trure. but when i click on deselect all it is showing nothing.

Comment: they are still selected checkboxes

Comment: Actually your else part will not run @Shabnam as you code on if condition that will every time go to inside if .

Comment: plaese check i have updated the new code . and plases tell me what changes i can do.

Comment: I edited my answer check Use **Below code to Select & Remove :** and reply

Comment: now just one question how can i print this in log . how can i see that my entries are going or slecting in arraylist.

Comment: I edited my answer of **Below code to Select & Remove :** , Check and reply

Comment: please one lat question.if i want select only 2 checkbox then it is not showing in logcat. when i select all then it is showing in arraylist.

Comment: if i have selected only two check boxes then it is not saving in arraylist

Comment: for that you have to add the code of that checkbox.setOn listner @Shabnam ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386832/android-checkbox-listener

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to access arrayList without initializing it. Use below code

```
public class SearchFragment extends BaseFragment {
String[] name={ "Chicago", "Los Angeles", "Japan", "Europe"};
Object arr;
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
TextView tv2,tv3,tv4,tv5,tv6,tv7;
CheckBox 
abc,abc1,a,b,c,abc2,abc3,abc4,a1,a2,a3,a4,b1,b2,b3,b4,c1,c2,c3,c4;
public static SearchFragment newInstance () {
    return new SearchFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
 container,
                      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, 
false);
tv2=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv2);


abc=(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.abc);
a=(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.a);
b=(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.b);
c=(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.c);

return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated (View view, @Nullable Bundle 
savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

ButterKnife.bind(this, view);


tv2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String value=tv2.getText().toString().trim();
        if (value.equals("Select all")){
            abc.setChecked(true);
            a.setChecked(true);
            b.setChecked(true);
            c.setChecked(true);
            tv2.setText("Clear All");

            arrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(name));



        }
        else {
            abc.setChecked(false);
            b.setChecked(false);
            a.setChecked(false);
            c.setChecked(false);

            tv2.setText("Select all");
            arrayList.clear();
        }
   }
});
}}
```

Comment: yes it's working but when i clicked on deselect it still showing checked boxes nothing happened

Comment: @Shabnam where is the function of `deselect/Click` ?

Comment: when 1 time click on tv2 all checkboxes will be selected when 2 times click on tv2 all checkboxes will be unselected