# Implementing Checkbox with cardview

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a card view in which I included a text view and a checkbox , I tried some ways to work it out but I didn't get there, My issue is that I want to use the checkbox of card view and set it onclick but to be used on my Mainactivity, because after putting it onclick, I want to execute some piece of code,is there any way to do that, thank you

Comment: You are using wrong listener. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386832/android-checkbox-listener

Comment: yes i corrected that but still dosnt solve my issue, i want to 
put checkbox OnCheckedChangeListener but that to be done on my main activity , since i m using cardview , i can only set it in my adapter class , usually when we want to put something onclick from adapter ,we use interface , is there way to put the checkbox of my cardview OnCheckedChangeListener in my main activity thank you mate

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnCheckedChangeListener only in adapter as it will apply to all the rows in the card view. Can you share your adapter and main activity code So I can have a broader view at your problem.

Comment: Well the reason why i want to apply OnChckedChangeListener because i want trigger a notification  after the click . this is my adapter   https://pastebin.com/yQH0b3gP

Comment: The reason why i need a check box , is because i m making a premier league app , so in the settings section , there is teams names along with check box for each team name , so if the user checks it , he ll be notified with notifcation to be triggered using broadcast receiver reminding them that their team plays a game that day

Comment: checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {  //check boolean here and send notification here
                    if(mylisten != null ){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            mylisten.checkboxclick(isChecked);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

Comment: Thank you for the anwser , i totally  understood what you sent to me , and i could easily apply it , just one more thing please , in my activity , i have some data that i retreived from api , which i want to pass to the notification as well to pass the team games , and games dates to be shown for the user in notification , what can i do about that if i have to use notification in adapter , this is my piece of code for that https://pastebin.com/5ZZPFCEt thank you

Comment: add this data into a list and pass it through the adapter. public spinneradapter(List<spinnermodel> arrayList, List<ApiData> apiDataList){
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }   When you set adapter pass this list in it. Accept my answer bu clicking on tick button if you like my answer.