# How to save a Checkbox state in android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I'm new to android studio and I just can't figure out how to save the checkbox state using sharedpreference. If someone can help me I would greatly appreciate the assistance.

```
class SelectAlertSettings : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mp : MediaPlayer

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.select_alert_config)


    }

    fun onCheckboxClicked(view: View) {
        if (view is CheckBox) {
            val checked: Boolean = view.isChecked

            when (view.id) {
                R.id.checkbox_proximity_alert -> {
                    if (checked) {

                        val proximityAlert = R.raw.proximity_alert
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, proximityAlert)
                        mp.start()

                    } else {

                        mp.stop()
                    }

                }

            }

        }

        val btnCancel : Button = findViewById(R.id.btnDone)
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener{
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That code is not calling `onCheckboxClicked` function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: checkbox listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386832/android-checkbox-listener)

Comment: @pi_hobbyist - did my answer help?

Answer (score 2):

To save a value to shared preferences, you need to do the following things:

1. Get a reference to the shared preferences object
2. Create a SharedPreferences.Editor instance
3. Choose the type you want to save in your shared preferences
4. Save the changes using commit or apply

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences).

```
val sharedPref = activity?.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
    with (sharedPref.edit()) {
        putBoolean("YOUR_CHECKBOX_KEY", checkboxState)
        apply()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To save the check box state as a `boolean` in shared preferences do the following:

1 - Get a handle to shared preferences:

```
val sharedPref = activity?.getSharedPreferences("preferences file key",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

2 - Write to shared preferences:

```
sharedPref.edit().putBoolean("key", value).apply()
```

3 - Read from shared preferences:

```
val value = sharedPref.getBoolean("key", defaultValue)
```

Read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) to learn more.

I also I recommend using [DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore) instead of `SharedPreferences`. `DataStore` uses Kotlin coroutines and Flow to store data and it's the recommended way to save key-value pairs.